# Use angular filter to search a dataset

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular object that i need to search through and render the output in html. The object has 2 properties, name and company

```
$scope.options = [{name: "test", company: "One"}, {name: "test2", company: "Two" } ..]
```

I have a text field that I search by name with an angular filter

```
<input ng-model="query" placeholder="Search" autofocus>
```

and in my ng-repeat i have this

```
 ng-repeat="item in options | filter : {name : query}"
```

which woks fine. What i need to achieve is add a dropdown like below and search by what the dropdown has, meaning if dropdown has name i search by name, if dropdown has company i should search by company. Below is the dropdown code

```
<label class="formgroup">by:
  <select ng-model="dynamic">
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="company">Company</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Is there any filter that I can use to dynamically do something like this?

```
 ng-repeat="item in options | filter : {dynamic : query}"
```

Comment: First of all in your ng-repeat, you said item in options... Where is $scope.options???

Comment: In my controller. That part work. I see everything correct. All I need is a way to search by a dynamic field, not a static one.

Comment: Can you show us your controller? And even better represent your form in a plunker or codepen? See mcve: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The only way you can achieve this is by making a custom filter.... Show us what you have tried..

Comment: I tried this: `<li class="repeat" ng-repeat="item in options | filter : {dynamic: query} ">` I need to do this in html with a prebuild filter.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/7X2258hD6QhfI6gw2X2b

Comment: I resolved this by adding a custom function serving as a filter.